# Proper way to create a POST in PHP in woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is this a valid `POST` request in PHP in a woocommerce plugin?
Is the syntax correct and will it work?
Are there any ways I could improve this?

Seems there are a lot of ways to do this in PHP and don't know about the positive and negatives to pick one.

Wordpress plugin docs recommend: `wp_remote_post()`
Someone else recommend `curl`.

And then this approach which I've used:

```php
protected function generate_vm_request($order_id){
        $order  = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $post_data = array();
        $post_data['x_account_id'] = $this->test_api_key;
        $post_data['x_amount'] = $order-> get_total() ;
        $post_data['x_currency'] = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0.0', '<' ) ?
        $query1 = implode('', array_map(
            function ($v, $k) {
                return $k.$v;
            },
            $post_data,
            array_keys($post_data)
            ));
        $vm_query  =  http_build_query($post_data, '', '&');
        $vm_url = $this->VMURL;
        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
              'method'  => 'POST',
              'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'content' => $vm_query,
            )
          );
        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        $result = file_get_contents($vm_url, false, $context);
}
```

What is the best way?

Comment: I'd probably use [`wp_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) just to  simplify things.

Comment: Would it be fewer lines of code? And is there a benefit over the way I've done it?

Comment: I think you could reduce it down to `$result = wp_remote_post( $this->VMURL, $post_data );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`wp_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) you can simplify your function down to:

```
protected function generate_vm_request($order_id){
    $order  = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $post_data = array();
    $post_data['x_account_id'] = $this->test_api_key;
    $post_data['x_amount'] = $order->get_total() ;
    $post_data['x_currency'] = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0.0', '<' ) ?

    $result = wp_remote_post( $this->VMURL, $post_data );
}
```